# Select points that are around a spot from a set of points

Tags: matlab, image-processing

maybe my question is silly for some of you but I can not figure out how to solve it.
I would like to select the black points that are around every light circle from the set of black points. The center of the circle (black point in the figure) is known (it's not always in the middle of the object).

Could someone please help me on how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

[You could see an example figure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0O9w2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There are circle detecting algorithms. One such algorithm in opencv is [HoughCircle](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html). It should be available in matlab.

Otherwise, you can do the following.
1. For the center points construct the [voronoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) region. 
2. The rest of the points are now divided into different regions.
3. For each center, associate only those points which is situated in its region.

It is a heuristics but freom your example it seems to be working.